# Insert 'n' rows based on DISTINCT values and populate new row values

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert-into

I have a table (Mailing) with a field (Filename) that has 3 distinct values across all records. Let's say the values are:

File1
File2
File3

I need to insert a record from another table (Seeds) into said Mailing table, based upon these distinct values and then update the Filename field with these values for the record I am inserting into the Mailing table.

So, if I am to insert 1 record, I will end up inserting the same record 3 times, each one having a distinct value.

To help give a little context, here is my basic `INSERT INTO` statement:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.mailing (
    Filename,
    Title,
    Forename,
    Surname,
    Address1,
    Address2,
    Address3,
    Address4,
    Address5,
    Address7)
SELECT
    '?' AS Filename,
    Title,
    Forename,
    Surname,
    Company,
    Address1,
    Address2,
    Address3,
    Address4,
    Postcode
FROM dbo.Seeds AS S
WHERE S.URN = 1
```

I've obviously hard coded the Filename as ? for now. I hope this makes sense?.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a `filename` field in `seeds`.  If so, you can append a number onto it:

```
SELECT Filename + cast(row_number() over (partition by filename order by filename) as varchar(255)) as Filename,
       . . . 
FROM dbo.Seeds S
WHERE S.URN = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon - actually there is no filename field in the seeds. Filename is in my main table with the distinct values, I will need to populate this for seeds when inserted